# Distributing iPhone applications 2.1 vs 2.0

Tags: iphone, app-store

Can iPhone applications compiled against 2.1 be successfully installed via iTunes on a 2.0 device?

I know iPhone applications compiled with 2.1 can *run* on a 2.0 device (assuming they're not using anything new from 2.1). But am not sure if iTunes will let the install take place.

Does anyone have concrete information on this?

I have not seen any apps on the AppStore that are 2.1+ only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe apps that are compiled against 2.1 will be marked as "Requires iPhone 2.1 Softwar Update" when viewed through iTunes. (but not when viewed from an iPhone - the iPhone's App Store app only displays a subset of an app's metadata.)

One example: [Caliper](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=289310044&mt=8) (it's under "Application Description->Requirements")

I don't know if this "requirement" is actually enforced, however.

Comment: It is enforced.  A co-worker of mine tried to install Toy Bot Diaries Free on his 2.0 iTouch, and iTunes wouldn't let him.

Answer (score 3):

No.

As has been mentioned apps compiled with 2.1 will be marked as requiring 2.1 in iTunes.

If you attempt to download a 2.1 app from the iPhone, or sync a 2.1 app via iTunes, you will receive a message that stated iPhone OS 2.1 is required.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes.

There have been some apps that dont work 100% in 2.1, but the two firmwares are pretty much backwards compatible

Comment: Yeah I'm aware that the firmwares are compatible. But during ad-hoc testing iTunes would refuse to load a 2.1 app onto a 2.0 device. If I build & installed via Xcode things were just peachy.

The situation is a little bit confusing.

Comment: I would assume that when it comes to actually deploy the app and send it off to the app store, it would work fine on both firmwares. Besides, if it works on the iPhone simulator, it should be fine

Comment: Uhhh the iPhone simulator is a really really really terribly bad way to see what actually works on the device (case in point NSXMLDocument)